# Grub fatal error - failed to install on dev/sda

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside with Windows 10 (using USB stick), but at the end of installation process a "fatal error" appears, saying that grub failed to install on `/dev/sda` and Ubuntu will be unavaliable. I have only one hard drive in my computer - `/dev/sda`.

`/dev/sda8` now is Ubuntu, 
`/dev/sda2` is EFI (windows loader)

PC is Acer Aspire E5-573G.

`Secure boot` option is disabled.
UEFI version is 1.37.

Comment: most likely you are setting up Ubuntu as a "MBR boot" setup and the PC is using an "EFI boot"  instead. When you boot to the USB does it give you two options .. one that specifies (UEFI) and one that doesn't. If so you need to use the UEFI one and I believe there is other things you have to change in your UEFI/BIOS. Do a search on installing Ubuntu on UEFI it should give you more information. I am not really "versed" in UEFI so I don't know the particulars.

Comment: I selected EFI option when created bootable USB. PC is using UEFI. So, probably the problem is not here.

Comment: ok sorry.. have seen that issue before so I figured I would mention it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in locked ESP partition. Here I describe the solution that had fixed the problem for me (thanks to that [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2329429)).

**Note:** Before doing something with ESP it's recommended to make a backup. Lets consider you already have it (or you are knowingly risky like me). Now:

To find out if you have the same problem, boot from the USB stick and start BootRepair. In my case it returned "*An error occurred during the repair. Locked-ESP detected.*"

To fix this:

**1.** unmount your ESP partition. In my case it is dev\sda2

**2.** run `sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/sda2` to repair it (of course you must place your own name of partition here)

After that I started boot-repair again (it reported success) and again installed Ubuntu (also success).

**For acer users:**
After ubuntu successfully installed, you need to add it's efi file as trusted to UEFI system. Otherwise your computer will not boot ubuntu like it doesn't exist. Turn on the computer -> F2 -> Security -> Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing -> HDD0 -> ubuntu -> grubx64.efi. Give it any name you want, save, reboot, again F2 and you will see it in the boot priority list.

**P.S.:** 
BootMode is UEFI;
SecureBoot is enabled;
Supervisor password is set